# Google Visualization Bar Chart in asp.net

Tags: c#

Hi I am using Google Visualization Bar Chart in asp.net for commercial purpose do i need to purchase the license for that

Comment: No Dnt Think so Go to ur work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its free you can use but the problem is it won't work offline,Please read FAQ section

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/faq#using-the-api